# Getting 404 page not found in the log using Codeigniter 1.7.2 + HMVC

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, hmvc

I am using Codeigniter 1.7.2 and HMVC (https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home).

I have these files and they are organized according to the HMVC:

```
system/application/modules/welcome/controllers/welcome.php
system/application/modules/welcome/views/index.php
```

In the `routes.php`, I have set up a route:

```
routes['welcome']='welcome/index';
```

Everything works if the url is in this pattern:
`http://www.mydomain.com/index.php/welcome`

But now I would like to remove the index.php from the url, so I created the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Then I set the `$config['index_page']` to empty:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Now I can access the page in this url pattern:
`http://www.mydomain.com/welcome`

Although everything seems to work, I find that every time I access the page, it generates a 404 page not found error in the log:

```
DEBUG - 2011-01-02 08:28:52 --> URI Class Initialized
ERROR - 2011-01-02 08:28:52 --> 404 Page Not Found -->
```

This is not specific to the `welcome` page, all pages are having the same problem.
I digged into the codes and discovered that this `404 Page Not Found` message is generated from the `MX_Router.php` that comes with HMVC. Specifically, it's from this function:

```
public function _validate_request($segments) {      

    /* locate module controller */
    if ($located = $this->locate($segments)) return $located;

    /* use a default 404 controller */
    if (isset($this->routes['404']) AND $segments = explode('/', $this->routes['404'])) {
        if ($located = $this->locate($segments)) return $located;
    }   

    /* use a default 404_override controller CI 2.0 */
    if (isset($this->routes['404_override']) AND $segments = explode('/', $this->routes['404_override'])) {
        if ($located = $this->locate($segments)) return $located;
    }

    /* no controller found */
    show_404();
}
```

It's the show_404() function that gets called and therefore I am getting that error message. But since I can access every page without any problem using the url pattern which has `index.php` removed.

Why is HMVC thinking there's no controller found in this `_validate_request()` function?
I will not get the 404 error message in the log if I revert the changes but this also means that I have to keep using the url pattern that has `index.php`, which looks pretty bad.

Anyone has encountered the same problem before?
Many many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem somehow relates to the favicon.ico, some web browsers automatically request yourdomain.com/favicon.ico and if there isn't one available, it generates a 404 error in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is in your .htaccess file. The official [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) actually has an example for this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Does the problem still occur with this code in your .htaccess?

Comment: Using this code, when I access the page without the index.php in the url, it displays `No input file specified.` in the web browser. But I can access the page without any problem after I add back the index.php in the url. I just have no idea what problem this is.